# Criteria API correlate

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria, criteria-api

I have been Googling but do not understand what the consequence of calling the method correlate of javax.persistence.criteria.Subquery en the Criteria API.

http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/criteria/Subquery/correlate_CollectionJoin_

This is from the book Pro JPA2 Mastering the Java Persistence API.

> When creating the criteria API query definition for this query, we
>   must correlate the employees attribute of Project and then join it to
>   the direct reports in order to calculate the average salary. This
>   example also demonstrates the use of the type() method of the Path
>   interface in order to do a polymorphic comparison of types:

```
CriteriaQuery<Project> c = cb.createQuery(Project.class);
Root<Project> project = c.from(Project.class);
Join<Project,Employee> emp = project.join("employees");
Subquery<Number> sq = c.subquery(Number.class);
Join<Project,Employee> sqEmp = sq.correlate(emp);
Join<Employee,Employee> directs = sqEmp.join("directs");
c.select(project)
 .where(cb.equal(project.type(), DesignProject.class),
        cb.isNotEmpty(emp.<Collection>get("directs")),
        cb.ge(sq, cb.parameter(Number.class, "value")));
```

What does this line do?
Join sqEmp = sq.correlate(emp);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It gives you access to the employee referenced by the main query so you can use it and its tables in the subquery

Comment: thank you. So it glues the queries together? What would have been the consequences of skipping the line mentioned above?

Comment: You wouldn't have access on the Employees within the `emp` Join object. Thus you would not be able to use `emp` in your subquery `sq` where you do the join to `Employee_.directs` collection.